# Implement SICP evaluator using Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I'm working on metacircular evaluator of `4.1.4 Running the Evaluator as a Program`, building which with Racket:

```
#lang racket

(require (combine-in rnrs/base-6
                     rnrs/mutable-pairs-6))

(define (evaluate exp)
  (cond 
    ; ...
    ((definition? exp) (display exp)
                       (display " is a definition\n"))
    ; ...
    (else (display exp) 
          (display " is something else\n"))))

(define (definition? exp)
  (tagged-list? exp 'define))

(define (tagged-list? exp tag)
  (if (pair? exp)
      (eq? (car exp) tag)
      false))

(define (driver-loop)
  (let ((input (read)))
    (let ((output (evaluate input)))
      output))
  (driver-loop))

(driver-loop)
```

After getting a box that reads input in DrRacket successfully, I type in `(define a 0)` and it turn out:

`(define a 0) is something else`

It could be recognised if I remove

```
(require (combine-in rnrs/base-6
                     rnrs/mutable-pairs-6))
```

But without which I wouldn't be able to call `set-car!` or `set-cdr!`. Is there an alternative for `set-` function?

Or could I choose what to import from `rnrs/base-6` and `rnrs/mutable-pairs-6` ?

Comment: Does expressions other then definitions work? If so, add the definition of `definition?` as it must be the problem.

Comment: How exactly did you call `eval`? I mean, how did you pass the parameters

Comment: @Rahn The problem does not lie in `definition?`. I made a quick test that evals the result of `read` and it succesfully recognizes the expression as a definition. Hence the problem must be how you are calling `eval`. The `exp` argument must be different from the result of  `(read)`, else it would work.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez `eval` added in.

Comment: @HyperZ `eval` added in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the bug:

```
(require (combine-in rnrs/base-6
                     rnrs/mutable-pairs-6))
```

Package `rnrs/base-6` and `rnrs/mutable-pairs-6` bring in something unpredicted that change `cons`(as well as `car`, `cdr`) leading `(define a 0)` not been caught by `definition?`

Solution:

```
(require (only-in (combine-in rnrs/base-6
                              rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
                  set-car!
                  set-cdr!))
```

Always put `only-in` in `require` to avoid any unwanted binding.

Answer (score 0):

It should run fine. I made a quick test with the code you gave.

```
(define (evaluate exp)
  (cond 
    ; ...
    ((definition? exp) (display exp)
                       (display " is a definition\n"))
    ; ...
    (else (display exp) 
          (display " is something else\n"))))

(define (definition? exp)
  (tagged-list? exp 'define))

(define (tagged-list? exp tag)
  (if (pair? exp)
      (eq? (car exp) tag)
      false))

(define (driver-loop)
  (let ((input (read)))
    (let ((output (evaluate input)))
      output))
  (driver-loop))

(driver-loop)
```

Running this in the racket language will give me :

```
--> is user input
-->(define a 0)
   (define a 0) is a definition
-->(list 1 2 3)
   (list 1 2 3) is something else
```

As you can see the right branch of the conditional was entered.

Are you sure the error comes from the `else` branch? Because your error message contains a `:`, `display` in the else branch don't.

EDIT : What exactly did you entered in the input prompt?
Confusion could be that a call to Racket's `eval` function needs a list as argument, `(eval '(define a 0))`. However if you enter this in the input prompt it won't work. You'll have to write `(define a 0)`, like a normal definition.