# SICP Ch5 eceval compiler in Racket: set-cdr! into quoted list (not a dup)

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

This is not a duplicate of
[set-car!, set-cdr! unbound in racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475366/set-car-set-cdr-unbound-in-racket) or
of
[Implement SICP evaluator using Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613416/implement-sicp-evaluator-using-racket)
or of
[How to install sicp package module in racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892793/how-to-install-sicp-package-module-in-racket),
but rather a follow-up question because the solutions proposed therein do not
work for me. First, the need: Section 5.5.5 of [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html), the compiler plus
explicit-control evaluator ([code here in "ch5-eceval-compiler.scm"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/code/index.html)), are
entirely dependent on `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` into explicit quoted lists. I
would like to copy and modify this code without a complete, bottom-up rewrite in
immutable form. I'd also accept a reference to a scheme implementation that can
run the code out-of-the-box or with some minimal, straightforward adaptation,
i.e., a scheme that has `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` or some
work-around. Neither guile nor racket give me an easy time running this code.

**EDIT**: mit scheme will load the eceval compiler. I'm leaving the question up for those who might want to get it going in racket (I would rather, for example).

Here is a deeper explanation, including the things I explored and tried out, and
how I diagnosed the quoted list as the deepest problem. When I hand-converted
the quoted list into an `mquoted` nest of `mlists`, the code broke in much worse
ways and the rabbit hole got much deeper. I had to revert after a couple of
hours of delicate brain surgery that failed.

Here is an MVE of the kind of structure that section 5.5.5 relies on. This is small, but structurally like the real thing:

```
(define foo '(a b))
(set-cdr! foo '(c))
```

The real thing starts like this:

```
(define eceval
  (make-machine
   '(exp env val proc argl continue unev
     compapp            ;*for compiled to call interpreted
     )
   eceval-operations ;;   ----------------------------------------------
  '(  ;; <<<<<<<<======== BIG QUOTED LIST CAUSING TROUBLE / NOT MCONSES!
;;SECTION 5.4.4, as modified in 5.5.7 ;; -------------------------------
;;*for compiled to call interpreted (from exercise 5.47)
  (assign compapp (label compound-apply))
;;*next instruction supports entry from compiler (from section 5.5.7)
  (branch (label external-entry))
read-eval-print-loop
  (perform (op initialize-stack))
  (perform
   (op prompt-for-input) (const ";;; EC-Eval input:"))
...
```

and goes on for quite a while. The evaluator is the "machine-code" in the quoted
list, and various generated code does `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` into registers
and environment frames and other things. The code fails on load.

There seems to be no easy way to convert the evaluator into immutable form
without a full rewrite, and I'm trying to avoid that. Of course, `set-car!` and
`set-cdr!` are not available in `#lang racket`, and I don't think they're in
guile, either (at least guile refused to load "ch5-eceval-compiler.scm,"
throwing a mutability error, on which I did not dig deeper).

One solution proposed in
[set-car!, set-cdr! unbound in racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475366/set-car-set-cdr-unbound-in-racket) is
to rewrite the code using `mcons`, `mcar`, `mlist`, etc. according to `(require
compatibility/mlist) (require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)`. Those compatibility
packages have no replacement for `quote`, so I tried writing my own `mquote`. I
spent a couple of hours on such a refactoring, but the exercise was not
converging, just going deeper and deeper down the rabbit hole and ending up with
even deeper problems. It seems that to pursue even a refactoring I must
understand more semantics about "ch5-eceval-compiler.scm," and if I must, I
might as well rewrite it in immutable form.

Easier solutions proposed in
[set-car!, set-cdr! unbound in racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475366/set-car-set-cdr-unbound-in-racket)
are to use `#lang sicp` or `#lang r5rs`. There follows three experiments that
referenced other answers on stack overflow:

```
#lang r5rs
(define foo '(a b))
(set-cdr! foo '(c))
foo
```

> ```
> Error: struct:exn:fail:contract:variable
>
> set-cdr!: undefined;
>  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
>   in module: "/usr/share/racket/pkgs/r5rs-lib/r5rs/main.rkt"
>              -----------------------------------------------
> ```

which points to a place where `set-cdr!` is clearly defined:

```
...
(module main scheme/base
  (require scheme/mpair
           racket/undefined
           (for-syntax scheme/base syntax/kerncase
                       "private/r5rs-trans.rkt")
           (only-in mzscheme transcript-on transcript-off))

  (provide (for-syntax syntax-rules ...
                       (rename-out [syntax-rules-only #%top]
                                   [syntax-rules-only #%app]
                                   [syntax-rules-only #%datum]))
           (rename-out
            [mcons cons]
            [mcar car]
            [mcdr cdr]
            [set-mcar! set-car!] ;; --------------------------
            [set-mcdr! set-cdr!] ;; <<<<<<<<======== LOOK HERE
            [mpair? pair?]       ;; --------------------------
            [mmap map]
            [mfor-each for-each])
           = < > <= >= max min + - * /
           abs gcd lcm exp log sin cos tan not eq?
           call-with-current-continuation make-string
           symbol->string string->symbol make-rectangular
           exact->inexact inexact->exact number->string string->number
...
```

Here is a similar failure with `#lang sicp`

```
#lang sicp
(define foo '(a b))
(set-cdr! foo '(c))
foo
```

> ```
> Error: struct:exn:fail:contract:variable
>
> set-cdr!: undefined;
>  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
>   in module: "/home/rebcabin/.racket/7.2/pkgs/sicp/sicp/main.rkt"
>              ----------------------------------------------------
> ```

pointing to code that only indirectly defines `set-cdr!`, but clearly in the
appropriate package:

```
....
#lang racket

(require racket/provide         ;; --------------------------------------------
         (prefix-in r5rs: r5rs) ;; <<<<<<<<======== PULL IN SET-CDR! ETC. HERE?
         (rename-in racket [random racket:random])) ;; ------------------------

(provide (filtered-out (λ (name) (regexp-replace #px"^r5rs:" name ""))
                       (except-out (all-from-out r5rs) r5rs:#%module-begin))
         (rename-out [module-begin #%module-begin]))

(define-syntax (define+provide stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (id . args) . body) #'(begin
                                (provide id)
                                (define (id . args) . body))]
    [(_ id expr) #'(begin
                     (provide id)
                     (define id expr))]))
...
```

I dig deeper into
[Implement SICP evaluator using Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613416/implement-sicp-evaluator-using-racket)
and find

```
(require (only-in (combine-in rnrs/base-6
                              rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
                  set-car!
                  set-cdr!))
(define foo '(a b))
(set-cdr! foo '(c))
foo
```

yielding

> ```
> Error: struct:exn:fail:contract
>
> set-mcdr!: contract violation
>   expected: mpair?
>   given: '(a b)
>   argument position: 1st
>   other arguments...:
>    '(c)
> ```

This error implies that the problem really is the quoted list. I don't have an
easy way to make the big quoted list in eceval into an `mlist` or chain of
`mcons`. I tried it and it's very verbose and error prone, plus I think the code
that loads eceval scans and patches that list, so it uses other list operations.
I had to revert after going south in a bad way.

Perhaps I missed some way to automate the transformation, a macro, but that's a
deeper rabbit hole (my scheme macro-fu is too old).

So I'm stuck. Nothing easy or recommended works. I'd like to either (1) know a scheme implementation that will run this code (2) some way I can implement `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` in racket (3) some other kind of work around (4) or maybe I just made a stupid mistake that one of you kind people will easily fix.

Comment: Note that `(set-cdr! foo '(c))` is **not** allowed if `foo` is a constant like `'(a b)`. It's undefined behaviour so I like to set `foo` to `"banana"` just in case it's not silly enough.
BTW Why don't you use `#!r6rs`? It does quotes to `mcons` in racket and work in all other implementations of R6RS.

Comment: on first issue, noted ; i adapted my MVE from SICP, and i think they modify straight into those big quoted lists eceval and compapp, but i’m not positive. on r6rs, i’ll try it! ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried (by either running `racket` directly or running it via DrRacket)

```
#lang sicp

(define foo '(a b))
(set-cdr! foo '(c))
foo
```

and it outputs `(a c)`.

This also works:

```
#lang r5rs

(define foo '(a b))
(set-cdr! foo '(c))
(display foo)
```

---

To answer your question regarding the implementation of SICP (which I am currently maintaining), you are correct that `(prefix-in r5rs: r5rs)` will import `set-cdr!`.

---

Update: I just installed Geiser and now experienced the same problem that you did when I `C-c C-b`. However, `C-c C-a` works as expected.

Personally, I would use `racket-mode` instead of Geiser.

Comment: still crashes for me in geiser. investigating.

Comment: See my updated answer above. In particular, use `C-c C-a` in Geiser instead.

Comment: ok, works for my MVE. I still get an error with the eceval-compiler, namely `ch5-eceval-compiler-one-file-racket.scm:457:9: module: identifier already defined
  at: tagged-list?
  in: (define-values (tagged-list?) (r5rs:lambda (exp tag) (if (pair? exp) (eq? (car exp) tag) false)))` but I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Will investigate this tonight!

Comment: that would be wonderful! I'd much rather use racket than mit-scheme (nothing against mit-scheme, of course; just a preference --- i use racket for teaching)

Answer (score 0):

Mit-scheme will load the eceval compiler from the code drop mentioned in the question. On Ubuntu, mit-scheme loads with `sudo apt-install mit-scheme`. The [geiser package of emacs](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) finds mit via `run-mit`. The problem is solved.